# The complier doesnt recoginze flags using makefile

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile a file using makefile, but I get a bunch of errors. Without makefile, it works just fine.
Why is it happening?
[image]

Comment: Hi, please do not post images of text. Prefer pasting the text in your question.

Comment: @limserhane: In this case a critical clue is in the image and wouldn't appear in the transcription.

Comment: @Joshua - Like what? Make file and output could be cut'n'paste as text into the answer

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right `gcc` - Some versions of Linux come with a version that has limited functionality. Perhaps check and/or install a good version

Comment: ... and check that the PATH is correct

Comment: How? I have 16.04 installed.

Comment: Is PATH pointing to it? [whereis](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis)

Comment: @EdHeal: With multiple copies of makefile open in editor and the error messages not matching the copy that's visible, what would you conclude?

Comment: 1. gcc is not working as expected despite whatever makefile is being use. 2. Are you sure the right makefile is being used. 3 the contents of that make file

Answer (score 0):

Tend to your editors. Your output doesn't match your makefile on screen, and you have your makefile open twice.

Close everything, open the makefile once, and fix whatever is actually broken.